# How to find the root password?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, password, root

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 installed with Wubi.

My problem is I cannot connect to my wifi and I cannot see my files at data.
It asks for the root password to login but I don't know it.

Comment: You need the root password to connect to your router? Like the WPA-key or like accessing the router setup interface?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Ubuntu, you must have created an User and assigned a password to it, right? By default that user is an administrator and can ask for root privileges. So whenever asked for root password, just key in the password of the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the password by following method:restart your system, go to recovery mode (inside advanced options for ubuntu), enter root option. now on command-line type `passwd` and enter. now enter new password, re-enter the password. afterwards type `reboot`. see whether your problem is solved.